# React Native: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, react-native

I have 2 components, DraggableCard and ChooseMachine (ChooseMachine uses a DraggableCard). When I reach the ChooseMachine component it returns me with the error: `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I don't have a clue on what child component is that's being called twice.

I've tried to remove the `Some Text` that's being passed as a prop to DraggableCard, which resolves the error, but DraggableCard doesn't show and that's not exacly what I need. It should display the DraggableCard and the text passed. I've already tried to put `Some Text` around the  tag but the problem remains the same.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'

import styles from './style'
import DraggableCard from '../../components/DraggableCard'

export default class ChooseMachine extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}>

          <DraggableCard>
            Some Text
          </DraggableCard>

        </MapView>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

DraggableCard component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class DraggableCard extends Component {

  render(){

    return(
      <View
        style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <View style={styles.smallHyphen}/>
        <Text>
          {this.props.children}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I expect to render the DraggableCard on the ChooseMachine component

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are seeing that on Android?
Try the below.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/1901

Basically, remove the child element from `<MapView>` and instead position it abolutely.

Comment: That helped! The problem all along was that I was opening the MapView tag which in this case should be self closed

Comment: God bless you, mate!