# Send data from Parent class to child class

Tags: react-native

How to send the Parent class data to the child class. Parent class data is changing every 3 seconds.
What I want every 3 seconds when the parent class data is changing the data is sent to the child class and change his state on the basis of data.

`parent class`

```
  export default class ChildPickRoute extends Component{
    ...
   onTimeChange = (Time) =>{
      this.Co_Time  = Time
    //this.Co_Time is changing every 3 seconds
    }

   render(){
  if(this.state.currentScreen == "showMap")
  {
    const {stopsData} = this.state;
    const {stopId} = this.state;
    const {stopSequence} = this.state;
    const {routeId} = this.state;
    const {pickData} =this.state

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapAnimateToRegion
        stopsData = {stopsData}
        stopId = {stopId}
        routeId = {routeId}
        stopSequence = {stopSequence}
        Data = {pickData}
        onRef={ref => (this.TimeparentReference = ref)}
        TimeparentReference = {this.onTimeChange.bind(this)}
        />
    <Slider
    data = {stopsData}
    StopId = {stopId} 
    StopSequance = {stopSequence}
    />
     <CoTime />
</View>
)
 }
```

`Child class`

```
class CoTime extends Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  console.log("coming to child")
}
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
  console.log("props", props)
}
 render(){
   return(
     <View>

     </View>
   )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send values via component's props. Like this...

`Parent comp`

```js
export default class ChildPickRoute extends Component{
  ...
  onTimeChange = (Time) =>{
    //this.Co_Time  = Time
    this.setState({ Co_Time: Time })
    //this.Co_Time is changing every 3 seconds
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.currentScreen == "showMap")
    {
      const {stopsData, stopId, stopSequence, routeId, pickData, Co_Time} = this.state;

      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapAnimateToRegion
          stopsData = {stopsData}
          stopId = {stopId}
          routeId = {routeId}
          stopSequence = {stopSequence}
          Data = {pickData}
          onRef={ref => (this.TimeparentReference = ref)}
          TimeparentReference = {this.onTimeChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <Slider
          data = {stopsData}
          StopId = {stopId} 
          StopSequance = {stopSequence}
          />
          <CoTime coTimeValue={Co_Time} />
        </View>
      )
    }
}
```

`Child comp`

```js
class CoTime extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log("coming to child")
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    console.log("props", props)
  }

  render(){
    const { coTimeValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <View></View>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, you should not use `componentWillReceiveProps` anymore. It has been masked as UNSAFE Method by React official.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Parent class will send data to child class only once time when the Parent class render first time, because Parent class component render only one time.  Parent class should send data every 3 second.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Just use a state instead of a class property. If Co_Time is updated, then parent will be re-rendered and child component will be re-rendered with new value of Co_Time too.

Comment: The parent component should not be re-render. using setState in Parent class the whole component will re-render every 3 seconds. I don't want it.

Comment: Why don't you want the parent comp re-render?

Comment: because of Parent component having `MapView` so that using setState, it will re-render the whole Map which is not good and then the user can't do some activity on Parent View.

Comment: You can let the parent component re-render, while you prevent `MapView` component re-rendering by using `shouldComponentUpdate()`. Another way is moving the Co_Time state to inside  `CoTime` component.

Comment: how to move Co_time state inside CoTime Component? is there is any another to pass the data from `Parent component's function`  to  `Child component`

Comment: Oh, I've just realised your logic is bind to `MapAnimateToRegion`. So, i gonna back to first suggestion, using `shouldComponentUpdate()` to prevent it from re-rendering.

Comment: you know why this error is occurring.. `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Comment: This may be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448778/react-native-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent